# mysql adding table appends "@@@" to table name

Tags: mysql

For some reason when I try to add this one table, `aux`, it always appens `@@@` to the table name in `information_schema.innodb_sys_tables`.  If I use `aux2` instead, it works fine.  Why?  See below for what I mean.

```
mysql>  select * from information_schema.innodb_sys_tables where name like '%aux%' and name like 'tsm%';
+----------+------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME       | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | FILE_FORMAT | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE |
+----------+------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+
|    67408 | tsm/aux2   |    1 |     54 | 67394 | Antelope    | Compact    |             0 |
|    67407 | tsm/aux@@@ |    1 |     54 | 67393 | Antelope    | Compact    |             0 |
+----------+------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

I have two scripts, the same except for the table name.

This is the one that  does NOT work:

```
CREATE TABLE `aux` (
  `AUXKEY` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AUXSTM` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSTS` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `auxuid` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `AUXSKU` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `auxskd` varchar(120) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `AUXQTY` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXEQT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXTAG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXETG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSEQ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXZNE` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXFLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXOID` varchar(26) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXLNN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXLLN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXLST` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXGRP` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXPLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTFP` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTYP` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXUOM` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXLOT` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCLS` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTSK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXITK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXSUB` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXSCT` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSDTR` datetime NOT NULL,
  `AUXLNK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXTSZ` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXPRY` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXWAV` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCPO` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXDID` varchar(26) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCAS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXRTG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCRT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXRDN` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXUM1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXPPS` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXPSQ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXTLR` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXMTG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXLCD` varchar(12) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSHDR` datetime NOT NULL,
  `AUXRVF` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXDNO` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `auxfid` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `AUXKEY` (`AUXKEY`),
  KEY `AUX_AUXLSTK` (`AUXLST`,`AUXLCD`,`AUXKEY`),
  KEY `AUX_AUXOID` (`AUXOID`),
  KEY `AUX_AUXSTSK` (`AUXSTS`,`AUXKEY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;
```

And here is the one that DOES work:

```
CREATE TABLE `aux2` (
  `AUXKEY` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AUXSTM` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSTS` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `auxuid` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `AUXSKU` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `auxskd` varchar(120) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `AUXQTY` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXEQT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXTAG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXETG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSEQ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXZNE` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXFLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXOID` varchar(26) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXLNN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXLLN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXLST` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXGRP` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXPLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTFP` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTYP` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXUOM` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXLOT` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCLS` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXTSK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXITK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXSUB` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXSCT` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSDTR` datetime NOT NULL,
  `AUXLNK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXTSZ` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXPRY` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXWAV` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCPO` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSLC` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXDID` varchar(26) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCAS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXRTG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXCRT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXRDN` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXUM1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXPPS` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXPSQ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUXTLR` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXMTG` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXLCD` varchar(12) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXSHDR` datetime NOT NULL,
  `AUXRVF` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUXDNO` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `auxfid` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `AUXKEY` (`AUXKEY`),
  KEY `AUX_AUXLSTK` (`AUXLST`,`AUXLCD`,`AUXKEY`),
  KEY `AUX_AUXOID` (`AUXOID`),
  KEY `AUX_AUXSTSK` (`AUXSTS`,`AUXKEY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;
```

Is `aux` reserved or something?  I don't see it in the list of reserved words, but that is the only thing I can think of.  Even running `alter table aux2 rename aux;` adds it, so `aux` is somehow significant.

MySql Version:
On Amazon RDS, I am using 5.7.42-log
On CentOS 6.5 dev server, I am using 5.6.51-log

Same behavior on both machines.

BTW, the first place I checked was MySQL reserved words, and I did not see it.  I only mentioned "reserved words" because I was grasping at straws.

I am doing everything from the command line.  So something like `mysql .... < aux2.sql`.  This is the method I can use to create tables.  I cannot use other tools because sometimes I dump databases to create duplicate copies, and that is how I found the problem.

Comment: Doesn't look like it is reserved: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: What is the mysql version that you use?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on phpmyadmin demo site using mysql v8.0.18

Comment: Versions 5.6 and 5.7 (more info in original post).  PhpMyAdmin is not currently an option for me.

Comment: Have you tried using the table, eg `SELECT * FROM \`aux\`;`? I'm just trying to rule out any difference between actual table names and what is shown in the `information_schema` output

Comment: Maybe... In MySQL the name of the table is also the name of the on-disk file where the table data is stored. But `AUX` is a name of pre-defined device on OS, so the file with this name cannot be created. For to solve this issue the postfix `@@@` is added.. This can be RDS or CentOS issie - MySQL 5.7 itself creates the table with this name freely. https://dbfiddle.uk/iKlXmT-J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-mapping.html

> On Windows, some names such as nul, prn, and aux are encoded by appending @@@ to the name when the server creates the corresponding file or directory. This occurs on all platforms for portability of the corresponding database object between platforms.

Comment: The reason is that these filenames have special meaning in Windows. Writing to a file named `prn` sends to the printer.